# What statistical model can be used to find how following variables relate?

Tags: statistics

I want to find the relationship between a disease incidence in a region and a number of other environmental factors such as temperature, elevation etc.

I have tables containing this data for a particular country.
The data files are raster files of the country map with each pixel having certain numeric value for the particular parameter.
Example [126, 540, 359...] say disease cases or [23.34, 19.02...] for temperature etc.

I have read about **multiple regression**, **Pearson Chi square test**, **t-tests** etc. But I didn't find them suitable: Multiple regression because what I read it assumes a linear relationship between the variables. Chi square test applies to categorical data. t-tests for small datasets.
I've also read about **EOF analysis** (Empirical Orthogonal Function) but it requires time series data. **CCA** (Canonical Correlation Analysis) but it finds the relationship between two sets of multiple variables.

**Which statistical method can I use to find the relationship between these variables?** I want to use a method that gives a relationship, say, more is the elevation, more is the number of disease incidence etc. Without assuming anything before hand like, "there'd be a linear relationship between the variables, so using linear relationship model." Also, is some method I mentioned appropriate but my understanding is not correct?

I don't  necessarily need to find relationship one to many, it'd be fine to use one on one methods.
On a side note, I'm working with GIS data and would use Python or R modules to find and plot the relationship. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with posting this question here, but there is a stats site in the SE network where it might attract more attention.

Comment: I apologize, I was unaware. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Multivariable nonlinear regression analysis could be a good choice, since it models relationships without linearity assumptions. Also consider the possibility of linearizing relationships by appropriate transformations (e.g., logarithmic, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can capture non-linear relationships in regression analysis by adding powers of a variable. i.e. $y=b_0+b_1\cdot x+b_2\cdot x^2$. You need to think about what sort of regression. In your case the $y$ may be a count (i.e. number of cases) in which case you need Poisson regression, or y may be a percentage in which case you need logistic regression.

That said I would start simple, assume everything is linear and just do standard regression. If the $y$ starts going negative of greater than 100% then get clever.